# Java generics question - Class<T> vs. T?

Tags: java, generics, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate validator and trying to create a little util class:

```
public class DataRecordValidator<T> {
    public void validate(Class<T> clazz, T validateMe) {
        ClassValidator<T> validator = new ClassValidator<T>(clazz);
        InvalidValue[] errors = validator.getInvalidValues(validateMe);
        [...]
    }
}
```

Question is, why do I need to supply the `Class<T> clazz` parameter when executing `new ClassValidator<T>(clazz)`?  Why can't you specify:

1. `T` as in `ClassValidator<T>(T)`?
2. `validateMe.getClass()` as in `ClassValidator<T>(validateMe.getClass())`

I get errors when I try to do both options.

*Edit*: I understand why #1 doesn't work.  But I don't get why #2 doesn't work.  I currently get this error with #2:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor ClassValidator(java.lang.Class<capture#279 of ? extends java.lang.Object>)
location: class org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator<T>
```

Note: Hibernate API method is ([here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3.0.cp03_fp01/api/hibernate-validator/org/hibernate/validator/ClassValidator.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `validate` method is yours, then you can safely skip the `Class` atribute.

```
public void validate(T validateMe) {
    ClassValidator<T> validator = 
           new ClassValidator<T>((Class<T>) validateMe.getClass());
    ...
}
```

But the `ClassValidator` constructor requires a `Class` argument.

Using an unsafe cast is not preferred, but in this case it is actually safe if you don't have something like this:

```
class A {..}
class B extends A {..}

new DataRecordValidator<A>.validate(new B());
```

If you think you will need to do something like that, include the `Class` argument in the method. Otherwise you may be getting `ClassCastException` at runtime, but this is easily debuggable, although it's not quite the idea behind generics.

Comment: Thanks, the `(Class<T>)` was the key!

Answer (score 8):

Because `T` is not a value - it's just a hint for the compiler. The JVM has no clue of the `T`. You can use generics only as a type for the purposes of type checking at compile time.

Comment: Thanks.  Why then can you not use `validateMe.getClass()`?

Comment: You __can__ use `getClass()` on any object reference... Just checked, compiler is OK with that.

Comment: You can use `validateMe.getClass()`, but there are caveats: if `validateMe` is `null` you get a `NullPointerException`, which may or may not be what you want. And using the current code you could pass a base class (for example validate this `Employee` instance using the rules for its base class `Person`). If you leave out the `Class` parameter that is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because [ClassValidator](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/hibernate/api/hibernate-annotations/org/hibernate/validator/ClassValidator.html) is requiring a Class object as its parameter, NOT an instance of the class in question.  Bear in mind you might be able to do what you're trying to do with this code:

```
ClassValidator<? extends T> validator = new ClassValidator<? extends T>(validateMe.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why can't you use `validateMe.getClass()` or `T.class`?

Comment: I thought that too... but I get this error: `cannot find symbol` / `symbol : constructor ClassValidator(java.lang.Class<capture#454 of ? extends java.lang.Object>)` / `location: class org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator<T>`

Comment: Nope: `found   : ? extends T / required: class or interface without bounds`   ,    `symbol  : method getInvalidValues(T) 
location: class org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator<capture#536 of ? extends T>`